# Create a entity mapper with cyclic dependencies

Tags: java, dependencies, cycle

I've a problem with a project i'm working on. I need to create a mapper that convert an entity object to it's VO (Value Object) form, i need to do that to limit dependencies between my persistence layer and my business layer but i've some cyclic dependencies that i can't resolve, look at this example :

I want to use a Competence object in my business layer so i use the mapper to convert the entity into a VO that is usable by my layer.

```
class Competence {
    private Domain dom;
}

class Domain {
    private List<Competence> lComp;
}
```

But when i convert a Competence object, i need to convert a Domain too and when i convert a Domain i need to convert the Competence list etc etc... And i don't really want to convert half of my database :/

I've thinking about converting half of the object or avoid some object to stop the cycle but it's dangerous and this is not really a solution for my problem :/

Haved you a solution to solve this ?

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: Are you using an existing persistence layer implementation (e.g. Hibernate) or are you managing persistence yourself?

Comment: I'm using EclipseLink to manage the persistence layer

Comment: Do you experience this issue because you are trying to convert the ValueObject to XML (eg. which happens automatically when returning the object from web-service)?

Comment: No, i need to minimize dependencies between my persistence layer and my business layer, so to do that i've created some VO that correspond to entity classes which are used by the persistence layer, i've created a simple mapper class with static methods in which i pass the entity or the VO object to convert into the other type, i don't know if i'm clear ? xD

Answer (score 2):

One standard mechanism to deal with this kind of problem is to recode to something like:

```
class Competence {
}

class Domain {
}

class CompetenceDomain {
  Competence competence;
  Domain domain;
}

Map<Domain,List<Competence>> domainsWithCompetence = ...;
Map<Competence,Domain> competencesInDomain = ...;
```

This breaks the **relationships** of the objects out from the objects themselves into a separate mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways around this.  First, you have to decide which side you want to convert.  Let's assume you want to convert `Competence`s and not convert `Domain`s.

1. Use an ID to reference the `Domain` inside the `Competence`.
2. Use a stub `Domain` object that only contains the ID and a minimal set of fields (not including `Competence`s) that you need.

Hopefully I've correctly understood your question.